# Titanium SDK 5.2.2.GA won't find iOS devices

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-cli

I have an app that worked fine last year on the earlier versions of sdk but now Titanium SDK 5.2.2.GA won't find iOS devices. I tried cleaning everything about appcelerator and reinstall but no luck. I also tried installing `node-ios-device` as a global package and in the titanium sdk 5.2.2 folder. What else can I do?
I get the following error:

```
2016-05-11T09:34:54.590Z | DEBUG  | [PLUGIN-LOAD] 0ms /Users/adi/.appcelerator/install/5.2.2/package/appc.js
(node:2212) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
2016-05-11T09:34:54.651Z | DEBUG  | [PLUGIN-LOAD] 61ms /Users/adi/.appcelerator/install/5.2.2/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/appc.js
2016-05-11T09:34:54.651Z | DEBUG  | run plugin: /Users/adi/.appcelerator/install/5.2.2/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium
2016-05-11T09:34:54.652Z | DEBUG  | [PLUGIN-LOAD] 0ms /Users/adi/.appcelerator/install/5.2.2/package/node_modules/arrow/appc.js
2016-05-11T09:34:54.654Z | DEBUG  | run plugin: /Users/adi/.appcelerator/install/5.2.2/package/node_modules/arrow
2016-05-11T09:34:54.656Z | TRACE  | plugin "arrow" failed its "when" function check, skipping...
2016-05-11T09:34:54.657Z | TRACE  | loading plugin "titanium" for command "run" CLI options via function
2016-05-11T09:34:54.658Z | TRACE  | loading plugin "titanium" for command "run" CLI options via array
2016-05-11T09:34:54.660Z | TRACE  | executing command "run" with the following plugins:
["titanium"]
2016-05-11T09:34:54.661Z | TRACE  | Attempting to load session info from config file
2016-05-11T09:34:54.662Z | TRACE  | check if session is invalidated
2016-05-11T09:34:55.350Z | TRACE  | session expiry 1463560847951 false
2016-05-11T09:34:55.351Z | TRACE  | session already loaded in opts.session
2016-05-11T09:34:55.352Z | DEBUG  | Titanium Downloads Last Checked: 1462957150130
2016-05-11T09:34:55.480Z | TRACE  | No project alloy hook; skipping update to 1.0.0
2016-05-11T09:34:56.100Z | ERROR  | An uncaught exception was thrown!
Cannot read property 'devices' of undefined
2016-05-11T09:34:56.101Z | ERROR  | Cannot read property 'devices' of undefined
2016-05-11T09:34:56.101Z | TRACE  | TypeError: Cannot read property 'devices' of undefined
    at iOSBuilder.<anonymous> (/Users/adi/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.2.2.GA/iphone/cli/commands/_build.js:298:11)
    at /Users/adi/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.2.2.GA/node_modules/ioslib/index.js:115:12
    at /Users/adi/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.2.2.GA/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:721:13
    at /Users/adi/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.2.2.GA/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:52:16
    at done (/Users/adi/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.2.2.GA/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:241:17)
    at /Users/adi/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.2.2.GA/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
    at /Users/adi/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.2.2.GA/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:718:17
    at /Users/adi/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.2.2.GA/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:167:37
    at /Users/adi/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.2.2.GA/node_modules/ioslib/index.js:85:6
    at /Users/adi/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.2.2.GA/node_modules/ioslib/lib/device.js:51:12
```

Comment: What NodeJS version do you use? Could you edit `/Users/adi/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.2.2.GA/iphone/cli/commands/_build.js:298:11` to log the parent object of `devices` ?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I forgot I posted this. The problem was indeed the NodeJS version, I had v6.2.0 and I installed v4.4.4. All works now.

Answer (score 6):

For anybody who encounters this, the problem is the NodeJS version, I had v6.2.0 and downgraded to v4.4.4. All works now.

Comment: Thanks, Appcelerator should fix this because now I can't run a SDK 6.0+ project and my other SDK 5.4.0 project separately...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Adi, I had the exact same issue v6.2.0 of Node and downgraded to v4.4.x and all works for me as well.

Comment: I'm glad this helped you.